# Remove a leading 0 in specific csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file called new.csv I am trying to remove all the leading 0's in a certain column called code.

```
id,name,code <br>
0,kevin,010 <br>
1,john,011 <br>
2,casey,020 <br>
3,micheal,030
```

This is just an example of what the csv file looks like except there are almost 1000 rows. I just want to remove the leading 0's from the code column.

I am trying to find a solution that I can edit a whole entire column for future reference too. For example lets say there was a leading character 'k' that I want to remove from a column.

I saw some examples online but it did not work.

This is what have below

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

with open('new.csv') as infile:
    title = next(infile)
    infile.seek(0)
    table = pd.read_csv(infile)

table.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2':''}, inplace=True)

table['code'] = table['code'].str.replace("0", "")
sys.stdout.write(title)
table.to_csv(sys.stdout, ',', index=False)
```

Comment: if you just simply cast it to int, there will not be any leading 0.  `int('000101')` result in 101.

Comment: also you don't even need `pandas` for this, it's overkill

Comment: perhaps you could use a text editor to replace the regex `,0+` with `,`

Comment: I am trying to find a solution that I can edit a whole entire column for future reference too. For example lets say there was a leading character 'k' that I want to remove from a column.

Comment: @KlaidiZiaj ok.  please update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `re.sub` to easily replace the leading zero. Use this regex,

```
0+([1-9][0-9]*)
```

And substitute with `\1` basically group1 content

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N2Xb7g/1)**

Try these Python codes,

```
import re

s = '''id,name,code <br>
0,kevin,010 <br>
1,john,011 <br>
2,casey,020 <br>
3,micheal,030'''

print(re.sub(r'0+([1-9][0-9]*)', r'\1', s))
```

Prints the numbers without leading zeroes,

```
id,name,code <br>
0,kevin,10 <br>
1,john,11 <br>
2,casey,20 <br>
3,micheal,30
```

**Edit:**

You can create this kind of function, which takes the filename as argument and generates a new file with name `inputfilename.out`

```
import re
from shutil import move
from os import remove


def remove_leading_chars(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as infile, open(inputfile+'.out', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        for s in infile.readlines():
            s = re.sub(r',m+', r',', s)
            outfile.write(s)


remove_leading_chars('data.txt')
remove('data.txt')
move('data.txt.out', 'data.txt')
print('writing done')
```

Contents of input file `data.txt`

```
id,name,code <br>
0,mmmkevin,010 <br>
1,mmmjohn,011 <br>
2,mmmcasey,020 <br>
3,mmmicheal,030
```

Contents of overwritten `data.txt` file

```
id,name,code <br>
0,kevin,010 <br>
1,john,011 <br>
2,casey,020 <br>
3,icheal,030
```

Comment: I am trying to find a solution that I can edit a whole entire column for future reference too. For example lets say there was a leading character 'k' that I want to remove from a column. Would you be able to rewrite not hard coding the txt content since part of the question is the data is in a csv file and I want to change it in the csv file.

Comment: I think using `re.sub` is good idea, but personally I would do it in bit different way i.e. `re.sub(r'0+(?=[1-9])','',s)` that is using zero length assertion instead of group.

Comment: @Daweo: Look ahead can of course be used as other way, but look aheads are comparatively slower than grouping pattern and grouping pattern is more widely supported in general, hence I preferred that. But like any answer, there are many ways to do the same thing. Good suggestion.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi well the data I included is just a couple lines because it is over 1000 names in the new.csv file. What if I had to remove all leading 'm' from the name column?

Comment: @KlaidiZiaj: Sure, you can substitute `,m+` with `,` to get the desired results. But like you are saying leading `m` can you show at least 2-3 sample data, so I can clarify how to go about it in various cases. What if you name also starts with `m` which you don't want to remove.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi there are no exceptions, just think of a csv file with names and every single name that has a leading m will have just the m removed. for example mike will be ike mart will be art

Comment: @KlaidiZiaj: Ok sure, that is pretty easy. Just need to substitute `,m+` with `,`. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/N2Xb7g/2)

Comment: I see the change being done but I do not see where you read it from the csv file and write it back into the csv file without the m @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi

Comment: @KlaidiZiaj: Do you want me to show you how you can read data from one file and write into another? Let me update my post with a sample code.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Let me know when you have updated it

Comment: @KlaidiZiaj: Added sample code for reading from file and generated cleaned text into another file. Let me know for any queries.

Comment: What would i have to do in order to rewrite the data.txt file and not create the data.txt.out file @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi

Comment: @KlaidiZiaj: I didn't knew how to do it, but quickly googling tells, remove old file and rename newfile with old one. Let me update my Python code in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192387/discussion-between-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi-and-klaidi-ziaj).

Answer (score 1):

You should try removing the `0` using a string slice, for example:

```
table['code'] = table['code'].str[1:]
```

Also, if there is a comma after the `0`, like this: `0,` then try using this instead:

```
table['code'] = table['code'].str[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider my example:

```
txt = '''id,name,code <br>
0,kevin,010 <br>
1,john,011 <br>
2,casey,020 <br>
3,micheal,030'''
txt = txt.split('\n')
txt = [i.rpartition(',') for i in txt]
txt = [''.join([i[0],i[1],i[2].lstrip('0')]) for i in txt]
txt = '\n'.join(txt)
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
id,name,code <br>
0,kevin,10 <br>
1,john,11 <br>
2,casey,20 <br>
3,michaeal,30
```

Note that for simplicity I hardcoded txt content. I used str methods: `rpartition` to split at last `,` and `lstrip` to get rid of `0`.

EDIT: You can treat `.csv` as plain text file and use `read` to get content, i.e. instead of hard-coding `txt` just do:

```
with open('yourfile.csv','r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
```

At end instead of printing `txt` do:

```
with open('yournewfile.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(txt)
```

Comment: Would you be able to rewrite not hard coding the txt content since part of the question is the data is in a csv file and I want to change it in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with replacing your line `table['code'].str.replace("0", "")` with below:

**1. This will remove any leading digit**

```
table['code'].replace('^\d', '', regex=True)
```

**2. This will remove leading 0 specifically**

```
table['code'].replace('^0', '', regex=True)
```

Please note: to permanently replace use it with `inplace=True`

```
table['code'].replace('^0', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I may suggest to cast to number while you  are reading from the file. example is `int(0001010)` will lead to `1010`.

by default DataFrame is guessing this column as a number so reading it will convert them to int.

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/random/d2',header=None,names=['W1','W2'])
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

## result

```
        W1  W2
0    kevin  10
1     john  11
2    casey  20
3  micheal  30
```

Update for a little more verbose version enforcing pandas/casting

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/random/d2',header=None,names=['W1','W2'])
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

dfNew=pd.DataFrame(columns=['W1','W2'])
rows,clumns=df.shape
for index in range(rows):
    tempRow=[df.iat[index,0], int(df.iat[index,1])]
    dfNew.loc[len(dfNew)]=tempRow
print(dfNew)
```

Result

```
        W1  W2
0    kevin  10
1     john  11
2    casey  20
3  micheal  30
```

Comment: while this is the correct approach this does not constitute a _complete_ answer, please provide one and I will happily remove my downvote

Comment: let me reproduce a txt file representing his question. there was not file.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution that I can edit a whole entire column for future reference too. For example lets say there was a leading character 'k' that I want to remove from a column.